# Rails - update directly in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

Delving into the documentation and the api, I seem to be missing how to update one field in multiple rows at once.

Something like

```
Table.select(:field).update("update to this").where(id: 4,5,6)
```

would be nice.

Does something like this exist? It would be much better than having to store everything in an array, set it to a value, and calling `save` every time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) method, for example:

```
Table.update_all("field = 'update to this'", ["id in (?)", ids])
```

Comment: Thanks! I also just found [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) where they explain how to combine it with conditions, limitations and more.